# PHP SoapClient: how to invoke another method when service has same method names

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm using PHP SoapClient with WSDL. Web service returns such functions:

```
0. BaseHotelSearchRsp service(HotelSearchAvailabilityReq $parameters)
1. HotelMediaLinksRsp service(HotelMediaLinksReq $parameters)
2. HotelDetailsRsp service(HotelDetailsReq $parameters)
```

When i'm invoking service in such way:

```
$mySoapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl_location);
$mySoapClient->__soapCall('service', array($params));
```

It always call method `0. BaseHotelSearchRsp service(HotelSearchAvailabilityReq $parameters)` with `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq` parameters.

Even `$mySoapClient` validates `$params` on `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq` suitable parameters (i.e. it does not include into SOAP request passed parameters which are not valid for `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq` data types).

Question would by how to call another service method ? i.e. `2. HotelDetailsRsp service(HotelDetailsReq $parameters)`

Comment: Are you passing objects using classmap, or `$params` is an array as well?

Comment: I'm passing `$params` as multidimensional `array()`

Comment: Hi @Auris, Did you get an answer or a solution for this, I am facing the same problem, please advice

Comment: Nope, I didn't have time to experiment more with `SoapClient` and `classmap` option, decided to create request manualy and send them with curl

Comment: have you solved this issue? also facing similar issue

Answer (score 2):

I presume each parameter `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq`, `HotelMediaLinksReq` and `HotelDetailsReq` inherits from a base struct, or maybe not. Nevertheless, if you use a different class for each struct type and uses the classmap option, it might work.

If it does not work, then I already faced this issue and had to override the `SoapClient::__doRequest` method in order to update the XML request sent in order to ensure that the sent element has the good type.

Did you use a WSDL to php generator to ease the request creation and sending process? Did you try [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i'll try to play with `classmap` and `PackageGenerator`.
Overriding `__doRequest` is not helping because SoapClient is validating parameters and does not include parameters into request which are not suitable for `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq` data type, so I would need to rewrite a whole request :)

Answer (score -2):

Its simple, call it as function:

```
$client = new SoapClient ($wsdl_location);
$response = $client->HotelDetails($params);
```

Comment: It shows error: `Function ("HotelDetails") is not a valid method for this service`

Comment: @Auris, try to change HotelDetails to HotelDetailsRsp or to HotelDetailsReq

Comment: Same error, works only `$client->service($params)` but same problem exists - by default it invokes service method with `HotelSearchAvailabilityReq` parameters

Comment: This is obviously a bad advice. The method name is clearly service, HotelDetailsRsp and HotelDetailsReq are clearly types.